# Insert multiple rows based on previous insertion

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5

I want to insert multiple rows in a table A and use the ids of those created rows to insert multiple rows in a bridge table B with two entries for each id.

Basically, there should be two rows for each created row in A in table B.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE for this with the `returning` clause:

```
with i as (
      insert into a ( . . . )
          . . . 
          returning *
     )
insert into bridge (a_id, other_id)
    select i.id, v.other_id
    from i cross join
         (values ('x'), ('y')) v(other_id);
```